# atos symbolicating only shows another address

Tags: ios, debugging, crash, nativescript

While debugging a crash log I got back from App Store Connect for a beta testflight for a nativescript app, LINE 2 (load address: **0x101318000**, stack address: **0x10135e48c**)

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x19dcd698c 0x19dbab000 + 1227148
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x19d9ff0a4 0x19d9f9000 + 24740
2   NativeScript                    0x10135e48c 0x101318000 + 287884
3   NativeScript                    0x101390d70 0x101318000 + 494960
4   NativeScript                    0x101e7e05c 0x101318000 + 11952220
5   NativeScript                    0x101e801b4 0x101318000 + 11960756
```

...atos only shows me another address (0x10004648c):

```
$ atos -arch arm64 -o myApp -l 0x101318000 0x10135e48c
0x000000010004648c (in myApp)
```

I did expect to see some debug information, like line, class etc.

Since slide is 0x100000000, atos' output 0x10004648c is the file address (file address = stack address - load address + slide). Which is nice, but would should I do with it?

- UUIDs from crash log, dSYM and app are the same.
- dwarfdump is not working, either

```
$ dwarfdump --lookup 0x10004648c --arch arm64 myApp.app.dSYM
warning: unsupported file type: 'myApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/.DS_Store'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 File: myApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/myApp (arm64)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Looking up address: 0x000000010004648c in .debug_info... not found.
Looking up address: 0x000000010004648c in .debug_frame... not found.
```

Any suggestions how I can proceed, what I did wrong? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

My own sourcecode was not "hidden" in the NativeScript part, it was far below and had its own line:

```
48  myApp                 0x10073f3e0 main + 29664 (main.m:58)
```

This part, and this part only, was symbolicated. And in the

```
Binary Images:
0x100738000 - 0x10073ffff myApp arm64  <44369b49886a3352946c8ea67713ff23> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AFD3BDDB-7A90-4973-AAEB-FC6D5839CABC/myApp.app/myApp
```

the UUID *...a67713ff23* was the only one fitting to one in the dSYM.